# Need help in PHP SQL relationship

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I've created one table that has quest_id and question columns and try to update them with PHP code, however only last statement in my code is actually updating the table, what I mean is that actually the last update command works, is there a way to update them all, or can someone help me fix the current error?

```
<?php
     $servername = "localhost";

    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","dnm","dnm","login1");

    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $q = array($_POST['q1'],$_POST['q2'], $_POST['q3'], $_POST['q4'], $_POST['q5'], $_POST['q6'], $_POST['q7'], $_POST['q8'], $_POST['q9'], $_POST['q10'], $_POST['q11'], $_POST['q12'], $_POST['q13'], $_POST['q14'], $_POST['q15'] );


    if($q[0] == '' OR $q[1] == '' OR $q[2] =='' OR $q[3] =='' OR $q[4] == '' OR $q[5] == '' OR $q[6] == '' OR $q[7]== '' OR $q[8] == '' OR $q[9] == '' OR $q[10] == '' OR $q[11] == '' OR $q[12] == '' OR $q[13] == '' OR $q[14] == ''){

         echo "<script>alert('Not all the questions are finished')</script>";
         echo"<script>window.open('class.html','_self')</script>";

      }
        else {


            $sql= "UPDATE login1.questions SET question = '$q[0]' WHERE questions.quest_id = 1";
            $sql= "UPDATE login1.questions SET question = '$q[1]' WHERE questions.quest_id = 2";
            $sql= "UPDATE login1.questions SET question = '$q[2]' WHERE questions.quest_id = 3";
            $sql= "UPDATE login1.questions SET question = '$q[3]' WHERE questions.quest_id = 4";
            $sql= "UPDATE login1.questions SET question = '$q[4]' WHERE questions.quest_id = 5";
            $sql= "UPDATE login1.questions SET question = '$q[5]' WHERE questions.quest_id = 6";
            $sql= "UPDATE login1.questions SET question = '$q[6]' WHERE questions.quest_id = 7";
            $sql= "UPDATE login1.questions SET question = '$q[7]' WHERE questions.quest_id = 8";
            $sql= "UPDATE login1.questions SET question = '$q[8]' WHERE questions.quest_id = 9";
            $sql= "UPDATE login1.questions SET question = '$q[9]' WHERE questions.quest_id = 10";
            $sql= "UPDATE login1.questions SET question = '$q[10]' WHERE questions.quest_id = 11";
            $sql= "UPDATE login1.questions SET question = '$q[11]' WHERE questions.quest_id = 12";
            $sql= "UPDATE login1.questions SET question = '$q[12]' WHERE questions.quest_id = 13";
            $sql= "UPDATE login1.questions SET question = '$q[13]' WHERE questions.quest_id = 14";
            $sql= "UPDATE login1.questions SET question = '$q[14]' WHERE questions.quest_id = 15";

        echo "<script>alert('Success!')</script>";} 

    if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
    } else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($con);
    }

    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Crazy you are.. :) `$sql` variable overwrites in each of line, and finally last line of `$sql` one is updated.

Comment: If it was me, I'd use INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE with the VALUES option. Much simpler and faster!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are executing only the last query. 
Use this instead of big bunch of code, where your `$sql`s are.

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 15; $i++) {
      $sql= "UPDATE login1.questions SET question = '".$q[($i - 1)]."' WHERE questions.quest_id = " . $i;
      mysqli_query($con, $sql);
}
```